# Scanner within scanner error

Tags: java

When trying to scan a text file and then scan each individual line in the text file to create an object I get the error below. 
Any idea on how I can fix this?

> Error: **java.util.NoSuchElementException** 
>           at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
>           at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371) 
>           at **MyZoo.readDataFromFile(MyZoo.java:111)**

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
    lineOfInput = scanner.nextLine();
    if(lineOfInput.startsWith("#")){

    } else {
        String animalType, species, name;
        Scanner newScanner = new   Scanner(lineOfInput).useDelimiter("\\s*,\\s*");

        animalType = newScanner.next();
        System.out.println(animalType);
        species    = newScanner.next();
        name       = newScanner.nextLine();
   }
```

Comment: What is the content it is trying to read ?

Comment: It is a text file containing lines of data, I read in the line using the 1st scanner. Then trying to scan each word in the line read in to assign them as variables. After I scan in the first 3, I want it to be read the rest of the data in the animal specific class

Comment: Why do u want to use another scanner? You already have a `String` use `String` functions like `split()`...

Comment: I have to use the 2nd scanner

Comment: Quick note: It'd be a bit better to use 
    if(!(lineOfInput.startsWith("#"))){ //If it *doesn't* start with #
        //Your code from within the else{} here
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said in a comment

*"It is a text file containing lines of data, I read in the line using the 1st scanner. Then trying to scan each word in the line read in to assign them as variables. After I scan in the first 3, I want it to be read the rest of the data in the animal specific class "*

your second scanner uses a wrong delimiter, due to which you are getting that exception.

try :

```
Scanner newScanner = new   Scanner(lineOfInput).useDelimiter("\\W");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad that helped you :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this in this way:

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    lineOfInput = scanner.nextLine();
    if (lineOfInput.startsWith("#")) {

    } else {
        String animalType, species, name;

        String s[] = lineOfInput.split(" ");
        animalType = s[0];
        species = s[1];
        name = s[2];
    }

}
```

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
 at MyZoo.readDataFromFile(MyZoo.java:110). Is the error I get if I do it that way

Comment: does each line contain the three string animalType, species and name?